# Best practice for an application with GUI

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

I'm about to start an application which will have both console and GUI interfaces. What I wan't to achieve is COMPLETE decoupling of application logic from interface. In future, I may also add web interface, and I don't want to change anything in my application.

Is there a good example (perhaps some open source project) where I can learn how this should be done properly.... also I'd appreciate advices/guidelines on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a good technique for logic and ui decoupling is the [Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) patterns and its variants (Passive View and Supervising Controller). There are writings by martin fowler and also many blog posts that present these patters.
I also suggest you to look for another variation of MVP, called [Presenter First](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presenter_First). theres a good [article](http://www.atomicobject.com/files/PresenterFirstAgile2006.pdf) about it, and also a good java [code sample](http://www.atomicobject.com/pages/Presenter+First) (look for java example)

Answer (score 3):

Fowler has a great overview of GUI architectures:  http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

I personally use the PresentationModel construct throughout my apps - it keeps the presentation side of things completely separate from the business logic.

Comment: Any good example that I could have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Build your core functionality (1) and your command line version (2) **first** (to the point where they are more or less functionally complete). Take care to carefully design / document your API. This way you can't intermingle logic and GUI parts early on.

An example for a good decoupled command line / GUI application would be `mplayer` for example (although one could argue that's it feels like a command line application with a GUI stuck on).